# Тема для научной работы по физике с элементами программирования

Tags: физика

Нужна тема для научной работы по физике с каким-нибудь превосходством перед другими физиками. Думаю использовать навыки в программировании. Теперь подскажете пожалуйста какую нибудь интересную тему или идеи объединяющий физ. и прог-е. Я немного знаю си, джава, си шарп.

Comment: >Нужна тема для научной работы по физике с каким-нибудь превосходством перед другими физиками

физика с превосходством перед другими физиками? Это как?

Comment: Превосходство это, я считаю, когда говоришь то что, профессора обычно не слышат от студентов. Другие физики, обычно, говорят то, что профессора тысячи раз говорили и тысяча раз слушали. (У нас в универе не один преподаватель по физике не знает программирования)

Comment: @Daulet сформулируйте пожалуйста вашу мысль грамотным русским языком.Это я сейчас не про грамматические ошибки, а про то, что ваша предыдущая мысль про профессоров - какая-то жуткая бессмысленная каша

Comment: Также уточните какой уровень научной работы необходим. Курсовая? Дипломная? Может кандидатская? (хотя сомневаюсь при такой постановке вопроса =D). Вуз профильный или нет? Какой раздел физики интересен?

Comment: А вообще программирование и физика связаны обычно так: берем какую-нибудь матмодель физического процесса и решаем ее численно на компе. Не нужно больших знаний программирования, нужно не бояться математики.

Comment: На какой хоть уровень и примерную область научная работа нужна? Научная работа по физике будет рассматриваться в первую очередь только как научная работа по физике, все остальное как дополнение и профессоров оно не интересуют. А так в списке что-то типа: программное моделирование физ. процессов, сбор и анализ информации; автоматизация физ. процессов; разнообразные ИИ и базы знаний.

Comment: Я, как вы уже заметили, не русский. Поэтому не смог правильно излагать мысль. Думаю дальше не стоит искривлять русский язык. Мне достаточно и этих ответов. Спасибо

Comment: Возьми задачу многих тел (механика), подробности в Берклеевских лекциях по физике. Считать равнодействующую сил на компе - в радость. Три проекции ускорения, там параболы самые обычные считаешь. Три координаты, побольше тел и временная сетка на сколько потянешь. И визуализацию забабахай, чтоб народ облизнулся..

Comment: Есть ещё фишка - рассчитать траекторию электронов в атоме. Та же песня, но сила притяжения распространяется с запаздыванием.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диплом по физике должен быть о физике. Программирование может быть максимум средством быстрого-удобного произведения каких нибудь расчетов. Любой нормальный профессор любой науки не станет принимать диплом, где этой науки не посвящена громадная часть работы.

Comment: В сферическом вакууме где образованием занимаются ради знаний а не ради бумажки или откоса от армии так оно и должно быть.

А вот в каких-нибудь заборостроительных вузах можно серьезно уходить в сторону если есть желание и кафедра позволяет. Один мой приятель на отлично защитил диплом по прикладной математике, где этой математики было процентов 15. Остальное - некая гуманитарная наука с ней не связанная.

Comment: @Volt кстати о заборостроительных вузах. Один мой знакомый в 2010 году вполне успешно получил диплом по специальности "программное обеспечение выч. техники", несмотря на то, что во время защиты с ним произошел небольшой, но довольно показательный  конфуз - его дипломная программа, которую он добросовестно купил у более сообразительного сокурсника, была в архиве, пароль от которого он не знал. Разумеется, уважаемая комиссия, а с ней и вся мировая научная общественность благодаря этой неловкой случайности оказались лишены счастья лицезреть очередной прорыв в отечественной науке

Comment: @DreamChild, =D. Да зачем она нужна эта программа: в документации к диплому требуют исходники, а любой нормальный преподаватель старой закалки умеет компилировать и исполнять в голове)

Comment: @Volt ну исходники (как и вся пояснительная записка) прикреплялись для истории, на защите их не смотрели. Как раз наоборот, на защите студент демонстрировал именно работу своей софтины

Comment: @Volt, уж лучше бы они занимались внутренним содержанием, а не процентами. Описать все важное на 50 страницах и потом еще влить туда столько же ненужной и путающей воды ради выхода на минимум по объему так себе перспектива. Не говоря уже о том, что важного в работе может и не быть вообще ничего.
@DreamChild, обычно наоборот, на саму программу даже не смотрят сильно, а слушают увлекательный рассказ о проделанной работе в виде презентации, пару вопросов и вердикт.

Comment: @Alex Krass ну хз. Скажем, в моем случае на презентацию  (ну, точнее, словоблудие про небходиомость и важнойсть разработки, сдобренное несколькими слайдами) и демонстрацию программы было отведено примерно одинаковое время. Как там было у вышеописанного мной человека, не знаю

Comment: @Alex Krass в вышеописанном случае было ок с внутренним содержанием, проблема в том что к специальности диплома внутреннее содержание почти не относилось)

Comment: @DreamChild, ну у меня была НИР, поэтому меня оценивали по теоретическому вкладу, программы даже не смотрели. Просто из наблюдений и рассказов, у большинства на защите программы могут не заработать по массе причин(всякие ошибки, несовместимости, доп. библиотеки и т.д.), поэтому на них ставку не делают изначально. Некоторым нерадивым студентам когда тянут вообще говорят вкладывать битую программу, на случай проверки - кто его знает, чего она не работает.